Loop doesn't clean the quotation marks
I've got this code that loops through a list of text files, opens them in Excel, and cleans the quotation marks from them. However, for some mysterious reason that I don't understand, it doesn't save without the quotation marks. I've tried different ways to clean the quotation marks but it still doesn't work.
I need the code to open other text files and remove the quotation marks from every single one.
Dim pathfile As String
Dim pathway As Workbook
Dim localcode As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wayfile As String
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wayfile = "pathfile"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wayfile)
Range("A1").Select

i = 1

Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("a" & i))
    Math = ActiveCell
    pathfile = "pathfile"
    pathfile = Replace(pathfile, "math", Math)
    Set pathway = Workbooks.Open(pathfile)
    Range("A1").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    pathway, saveas fileformat:=xlTextWindows
    pathway.Close
    pathfile = "pathfile2"
    pathfile = Replace(pathfile2, "math", Math)
    Set pathway = Workbooks.Open(pathfile)
    Range("A1").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    pathway, saveas fileformat:=xlTextWindows
    pathway.Close
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(camin)
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wb.Close

MsgBox "ok"


I don't think your code can pass VBA complier. that it, it's no way to run it. eg. ReplaceFormat:=FalseFormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2 . What's data on Col A?
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Yeah, pathway, saveas fileformat:=xlTextWindows looks sus.


I need the code to open other text files and remove the quotation marks from every single one.

You really do not need Excel for such a thing. Directly open the text file, replace the text and write it back to the text file. Is this what you are trying?
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String
    Dim FlName As String
        
    '~~> Change this to the relevant text file
    FlName = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\test.txt"
        
    '~~> Open text file in 1 go and read it
    Open FlName For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    
    '~~> Replace double quotes
    MyData = Replace(MyData, Chr(34), "")
        
    '~~> Write back to text file.
    Open FlName For Output As #1
    Print #1, MyData
    Close #1
End Sub

If you have a list of text files then you can convert the above procedure into a Function.

Split/Join is not necessary in this case. Replace(MyData, Chr(34), "") may save time.

Ah yes! You are right! @taller. May I safely blame this on my lack of morning coffee? (Updated the post)

Absolutely! It's the classic case of 'before-coffee syndrome' striking again.

Worked flawlessly, thank you very much. I just don’t understand the part about turning it into a function and how this works when applying it to other files. I have many other text files that need to have the quotation marks removed, and I want to systematize that.

Put the code either in Private Sub ReplaceQuotes(Fl as String) or in Private Funtion ReplaceQuotes(Fl as String) as Boolean and then simply pass the file name with path to the procedure or function in a loop. Use a Function if you want to check if any replacing was done else simply use the procedure. @MatheusDonizeti

You really help me friend but i dont have any clue about how to do that, i did some search but i still dont get it. Anyaway, thank u very much
